# POST action SESSION variables Deletes

Tags: php, javascript, session

I have an index.php contains a javascript code to change my form action

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {
document.getElementsByName("myproject")[0].onchange=function() {
var path = this.value;
if (path) this.form.action=path+'/main.php';
}
}
</script>
```

this script changes my form action everytime i change its value, then i have also a

```
<form action = "" method = "POST"><table>
<td>Select Project: </td><td><select name="myproject" id="myproject">
<td>USERNAME: </td><td><input type="text" name="user" id="user"/></td>
<td>PASSWORD: </td><td><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"/></td>
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Exam1">Exam1</option>
</select></td>
<input type = "submit" name="login"/>
</form>
```

and i also have a php code. this ive got

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
$_SESSION['user'] = "";
$_SESSION['pass'] = "";
if ($_POST['login'])
{ 
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
$_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
?>
```

when i redirected to my Exam1/main.php , i lose the SESSION variables. my Exam1/main.php contains this code to determine if i got the session variables

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
$mainuser = $_SESSION['user'];
$mainpass = $_SESSION['pass'] ;
echo $mainpass.$mainuser;
?>
```

Why am i losing the session variables.

Comment: How do you preform the redirect ? please post all the *relevant* code

Comment: EDITED: when i click the submit button login. that is the thing to triger the form action which is equal to (Exam1/main.php)
everytime i change the value of my `<select>` it changes the form action of my form.

Comment: before re-direct did you check weather $_SESSION['user'] has the correct values ?

Comment: @dilantha ,yes. first i put comments in my script so that i wont have a form action. then i can echo the session variables.

Comment: I have a little confusion about the flow. You have set the session data in your index.php. I Believe that will get executed when user submit the form with out changing the value from your <select>. But if you change the value of <select> and then submit i dont see any place where you have set values to the session variables

Comment: put error_reporting(E_ALL) for better debuging...

Comment: @Dilantha how should i do that . when i change the value of my select how can i start the session please help

Answer (score 1):

you are initializing the session two time`session_start()`us

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the php code you are having in `index.php` in `main.php` instead. Your form action is `main.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
$_SESSION['user'] = "";
$_SESSION['pass'] = "";
if ($_POST['login'])
{ 
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
$_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
?>
```

As redirect is to `main.php` `$_POST` data is available there only to be assigned to the `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the PHP is located in the same file as the form inputs this should all work. A few things to check out is to make sure your Apache config allows for _SESSION data, I know some hosts have this off by default, although no good ones do.

Also make sure you are initializing session_start() at the beginning before any other scripts that require session data.

If this may not be the case then what I am thinking is you are resetting the variables somehow. Try removing:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = "";
$_SESSION['pass'] = "";
```

As this is semi redundant when setting them with the actual information.

Just a side tip, as I am sure you will be using this for a login form be mindful of your security measures. Once you have your database connected, use the stored $_SESSION user and password (md5'ed) to confirm the authentication on each secure page.

If you would like an example of something I have a script that I use I could share.

Comment: i also tried to delete that sir, but still ,, i got no session in my Exam1/main.php , the session started as the page calls the php codes. for all i know php codes are always the first to be executed. correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

change `if ($_POST['login'])` 
to `if (isset($_POST['login']))`

and you are also missing a close `}`

Comment: i tried you answer but still i got no session in my Exam1/main.php

Answer (score 0):

This is what i understood

```
 <?php

    if ($_POST['login'])
    { 
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
    }
    ?>
```

This is where you are assigning values for session variables inside your index.php. This will Only get executed if you submit your form without changing values from your **select**  .because **form** will not have any value for **action** initially.

```
<form action="">
```

So it will get submitted to the same page and assign $_POST['user'] to $_SESSION['user']

Otherwise there is no values assigned to **$_SESSION['user']** and **$_SESSION['pass']**.

So if you change the value from your select and submit the form when it re-directs to Exam1/main.php there are no values assigned to **$_SESSION['user']** and **$_SESSION['pass']**

Comment: How can i store values in my session when i change the value of my select sir

Comment: In your Exam1/main.php you can assign values in the similar way that you have done in index.php. add this to your Exam1/main.php  . if ($_POST['login'])
    { 
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
    }

Comment: i used that code.. i change my code because when i click the logout link in my main.php then i click the back button,, the $_POST variables are still recognize by my main.php thats why it is still logged in.

Comment: Then in the place where you handle the logout. you should put session_destroy() and $_SESSION['user'] = "";
$_SESSION['pass'] = "";

Comment: yes i did that all of the destruction to destroy that piece of session cant be destroy. these are my destruction codes `<?php
error_reporting(0);
unset($_SESSION['user']);
unset($_SESSION['pass']);
session_unset();
$_SESSION = array();
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
session_destroy();
echo " <script> window.location.href = '../index.php'; </script>";
exit();
?>`

Comment: Try to use session_start(); on top of all of the things that you have done there.put session_start() on top of that page

Comment: i get why i can still access the main.php if i press the back button, because of the POST variables, how to unset all the post variables after clicking logout.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use and change value of `$user` and `$pass` somewhere after:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
$_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
```

I don't now if it's bug or by design, but:

```
$_SESSION['a']=10;
echo "{$_SESSION['a']}<br>"; //will print 10
$a=20;
echo "{$_SESSION['a']}<br>"; //will print 20!
```

it was a big surprise for me, when I used `$_SESSION['id']`...

Comment: It will work that way, if PHP setting register_globals is On.